# How does crawler/Search Engine traverse the web?

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

How does crawler of commercial search engine traverse the web:
"Identifying seed pages and through connected links find other pages"
OR
"Index every file under websites wwwroot directory."

in the case of later option search engine should even have indexed things which are not reference by any other page?

Answer (score 1):

A reference must exist. It can be

- regular HTML href allowed for indexation
- link in sitemaps.xml
- link in robots.txt allowed for a crawler
- reference provided by a webmaster in his search engine backoffice
- etc.

It could be any other link.

Comment: so the commerical search engine don't crawl the directory of the site through wget-m ?

Comment: @David actually no. Since the most of serious projects don't allow directory listing for security reasons. And even more, URL structure do not always reflect directories structure (that's obvious).  Also, if I'm not mistaking, wget -m is just FTP mirroring option.

Comment: @David I'm sure wget was not developed as a core of some commercial search engine:-) There are a lot of standarts de-facto which a crawler must support: sitemaps in xml format, robots.txt restriction, links indexation/following limitations, etc. That's a bit more difficult than simple mirroring.

Comment: thanks for explaining me. Will it not be certianly helpful if crawler also incorporate the file indexing based on accessing the website wwwroot. That way it can index any inaccessible pages by the method described above?

Comment: A crawler uses links but bot a files. It downloads a home page and the all links allowed for following recursively. Probably that's what you mean.

Comment: @David, do you want to give the crawlers your username and password so they can index the wwwroot directory? And another thing: these days the wwwroot directory may contain only a handful of actual pages with no content in them (such as in the case of ASP, JSP, etc), so indexing them is kinda pointless. Most of the content is dynamically generated, so the crawler must mimic the user behavior which would result in that dynamic content and that behavior never involves looking at the wwwroot directory.